# Siri not respond when using Shortcut

Tags: swift, siri

I am trying to present specific ViewController with using Siri Shortcut. The steps are:

1. In Info.plist I created a row "NSUserActivityTypes" array. Item 0 is com.testSiriShortcut.makePresent
2. I created method for Activity, called in viewDidload()

   ```
   func activity(){
   let activity = NSUserActivity(activityType: "com.testSiriShortcut.makePresent")
   activity.title = "Make View Red"
   activity.userInfo = ["present" : "Controller"]
   activity.isEligibleForSearch = true
   activity.isEligibleForPrediction = true
   activity.persistentIdentifier = NSUserActivityPersistentIdentifier(rawValue: "com.testSiriShortcut.makePresent")
   activity.suggestedInvocationPhrase = "View Page"
   self.userActivity = activity
   activity.becomeCurrent()
   ```

3.In AppDelage

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {

    let viewController = window?.rootViewController as! ViewController
    viewController.changeColor()
    return true
}
```

4.In settings, I turn on "Display Recent Shortcuts" and "Display Donations on Lock Screen"

Answer (score 0):

Don't forgot to enable Siri in **Capabilities** section of your project's settings.

[image]